# Can WMQ's SVR Channel be connected with multiple RQSTR channels?

Tags: ibm-mq

We are new to WebSphere MQ and we would like to know if we can create 2+ `RQSTR` channels in different QMgrs, connecting only one `SVR` channel on the server, like:

Channel Name: `CH1 (RQSTR) -----> CH1 (SVR)`

Then on another QMgr, another Channel Named: `CH1 (RQSTR) -----> CH1 (SVR)`

When we try to start the 2nd CH1, we got error message like "channel is in use".

We looked up quite a lot documents and forums all saying it seems we could create multiple instance of an `RQSTR`, so can those all be connected to our server through one `SVR` channel? Or do we simply have to create as many as `SVR` channels on the server for the `RQSTR` to pair up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A `SVR` or `SDR` channel connects to one and only one remote destination at a time.  It is possible to have a `SVR` or `SDR` defined on multiple QMgrs come to a single `RCVR` or `RQSTR` on a single QMgr.

This is also true in an MQ cluster.  A QMgr's `CLUSRCVR` accepts connections from all nodes in the cluster.  Each of those nodes auto-defines a matching `CLUSSDR` of the same name.  Thus in a cluster there will be one inbound channel named `CLUSTER.QMGR` and one `CLUSSDR` on each remote QMgr that also has the name `CLUSTER.QMGR`.

Channels manage messages in transactional batches.  An outbound channel has one destination so that if a batch ever fails, it knows to which remote node it has to connect in order to reconcile the transaction.  An inbound channel keeps track of multiple inbound connections separately.

The `RQSTR`/`SVR` channels are designed for the case that a firewall will allow connections initiated only from the inside.  In order to get inbound messages, the `RQSTR` starts the channel.  This also means that the `SVR` cannot hang up the socket and will accept a connction from any `RQSTR` that can start it.

Contrast this with the behavior of a `RQSTR`/`SDR` pair.  In that case, the `SDR` receives the start request from the `RQSTR` but then immediately closes the socket and proceeds to connect to whatever is in its `CONNAME`.

When I have a B2B channel connection, I always use a `RQSTR`/`SDR` pair.  My `RQSTR` can initiate the business partner's `SDR` which is often helpful if I'm sending transactions but no messages are coming back.  If I start my `RQSTR` and the channel comes up, that rules out connectivity issues.  If messages then flow across, I know the app on the other end is up but channel triggering is not working.  If the channel starts but no messages arrive, I know the remote app is down.

Then when I call the business partner to report the outage and can tell them *exactly* what's wrong on their end, they think I'm a genius.  Not that I do it to make people think I'm a genius, but they're generally a lot more willing to take my calls if I'm usually accurate with the diagnosis.

The `RQSTR` channel was built on the assumption that you would use it with a `SVR` and therefore doesn't have `ADOPTNEWMCA` capabilities.  That's the only down side.  If the network is generally reliable, it's not much of a down side so I use `RQSTR`/`SDR` pairs a lot.

So to sum up, the `SVR` channel is not intended to connect to multiple remote nodes *simultaneously*.  It is intended to connect to any *one* of multiple remote nodes at a time.  Since any properly configured `RQSTR` can start a `SVR` use the `SVR` only when you legitimately need to point it to different locations that are decided at run time and without making changes to the channel definition.  Otherwise use a `SDR` with multiple instances in the `CONNAME` or use a classic `SDR` channel and change the `CONNAME` during the failover.

Comment: Thanks so much Rob you just saved our day!

Comment: For an RQSTR to connect SVR we need to specify the IP address and the open the port of the SVR, but somehow due to our business logic we can't do that on the multiple SVR side. So at first we thought about using SVRCONN, but we end up have performance issue when "get" (5 gets in 1 second, that's too slow). If you have any better suggestion for us that will be perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: I'd have to better understand the use case.  Feel free to contact me directly if you like (email is in the profile) but once we iron out the details it'd be nice to record the Q&A here for others.  It kinda sounds like you want either a cluster or a B2B gateway.  See also: http://ibm.co/14Pqfxq